Disable default application window transparency whe dragging
As the title says HOW can i disable this behavior of the Windows 10? When I click and move/drag any application window the window background turns semi-transparent automatically as on included picture:

I'm developing some application that manipulates the window transparency on it's own and this default system behavior interfere whit behavior of my code.
I've tried to play with "Transparency effects" system settings in the Colors settings and with my graphic card software (Ati Radeon) BUT nothing helped!

I was unable to reproduce this behavior on any of Windows 10 systems. What third-party applications do you have installed on your system?

Simple:

Press Windows, type control pan and select Control Panel.
Select the System CPL.
Select Advanced system settings.
In the System Properties dialog, select Performance      Settings.
In the Performance Options dialog, check Show windows contents while dragging.

Caveat: On slower PC's, this might cause a subtle slowdown... or not.

Note that there two "flavors" of Control Panels/Settings, this one being similar to that in older versions of Windows, and the other (e.g., settings to Personalize the desktop) in a newer style. Some controls are found in both, and some in just one or the other. As R W Emerson stated, "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds."
Ah... but Microsoft has been rationalizing that situation for Windows 11, deprecating the classic Control Panel. However, some settings are no longer available in Windows 11, such as Taskbar placement.
